# Invalid filename after converting base64 string to blob

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

I am using the following function to convert a base64 string to blob. This is working fine. However, when I upload the file to a third party API, it fails. The reason is because the API expects proper fileName(with extension) and the blob I create doesn't seems to have it. It assigns the filename "blob" instead of "blob.jpg"

Here is the request I traced:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarytqD15GSBoU08Xz1l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

How can I get the filename when I convert the string to Blob? Here is the function:

```
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
    return blob;
}
```

Comment: The Blob object does not have a filename at all, and has nothing to do with `filename` attribute of the `Content-Disposition` header. You should probably show the code that creates and sends the request.

Comment: @SergeyPetunin thanks man! You are right indeed. I've updated my question and provided the solution.

Comment: @user1640256 It would be much better if you posted an answer and accepted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While appending the image data to form, I was doing like:

```
formData.append('image', BlobICreatedFromTheAboveFunction);
```

The correct way to assign image name is:

```
formData.append('image', BlobICreatedFromTheAboveFunction, "Whatever.jpg");
```

Comment: I never thought of changing file name before form submit. Nice. I will keep in mind.